# Keep Twilio sending sms after failure?

Tags: php, twilio

So i´m using the Twilio API to send sms.

I get usr names and nr from my database that i put in an PHP array.
Then i send SMS with a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($usrs as $number => $name) {

    $sms = $client->account->messages->create($number,
        array(
            'from' => "xxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            'body' => "Hi $name. $text"
        )
    );

    // Display a confirmation message on the screen
    echo "Sent message to $name <br>";
}
```

This code is what is custom.
And it echo out success.

But if a number isn´t valid the process will stop with a error message like:

```
Sent message to David
Sent message to Elsa
Sent message to Adam
Failure notice: the number is not a valid phone number...
```

and here the loop breaks..

What i´d like is the loop to print out the failure message but still send the one on in the array that comes after the failure.. without breaking the loop.

The error message must come from the API dist file?
Because i cannot se any error handling in my custom Php file..

Comment: Is it an exception? In which case use a try catch around the SMS create call and handle accordingly.

Comment: @JonStirling, beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you need to use `try{}` and `catch{}`.

Here is an example:

```
    // Step 1: set our AccountSid and AuthToken from https://twilio.com/console
    $AccountSid = "XXX";
    $AuthToken = "XXX";

    $client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);           

foreach ($usrs as $number => $name) {
    try {
        $sms = $client->account->messages->create(

            // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
            $number,

            array(
               // Step 2: Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number
                // that you've purchased
                'from' => "+XXXXXXXXXXX",

                // the sms body
                'body' => $sms
            )
        );

        // Display a confirmation message on the screen
        echo "Sent message to $name";

    } catch (TwilioException $e) {
        die( $e->getCode() . ' : ' . $e->getMessage() );
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this! Notice that you missed the foreach loop in your answear ;D